# the type of "OBJETO" is erroneuos

Tags: java, java-8

Estou estudando concorrência, e estava tentando fazer um codigo usando o *semaphore*, e es que surgiu esse erro

> "the type of ProcessadorThread(int, Semaphore) is erroneuos"

quando eu tentei executar.

estou usando o NetBeansIDE, e gostaria de saber o que é este erro.

Classe onde o erro ocorre:

```
package threadsemaforo;

import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class ThreadSemaforo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numeroDePermicoes = 2;
    int numeroDeProcessos = 6;
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(numeroDePermicoes);
    ProcessadorThread[] processos = new ProcessadorThread[numeroDeProcessos];
    for (int i = 0; i < numeroDeProcessos; i++) {
        **processos[i] = new ProcessadorThread(i, semaphore);**
        processos[i].start();
    }   

    }

}
```

Comment: Coloque o código dos construtores da classe `ProcessadorThread`.

Comment: achei o problema, estava faltando eu implementar mais uma classe! agora consegui

Comment: @renanmateus por favor, coloque a solução como uma resposta e marque-a como resolvida. Outras pessoas poderão se beneficiar dessa resposta.